# Break into C# debugger for divide by zero

Tags: c#, exception, debugging, nan, divide-by-zero

I'm using C# with the XNA library and I'm getting NaNs cropping up in my Vector3 objects. Is there a way to break into the debugger when the offending calculation happens (e.g. a divide by zero)?  Currently the program just continues running.  I'm using VS2008 Professional.  All the exceptions in the Exceptions dialog are selected in the "user-unhandled" column.

Edit: To clarify, I can't work out where the bad calculation is.  This is why I want the debugger to break automatically.  Setting breakpoints is not a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly dividing a double/float by zero gives Infinity/-Infinity depending upon whether the double is positive or negative.  Only a zero double/float divided by zero gives NaN.  In either case, no exception will be thrown.

You should be able to use conditional breakpoints to detect when a particular variable gets set to one of these values.  Be careful when checking for NaN though, as NaN != NaN.

```
double a = double.NaN;
Console.Out.WriteLine(a == double.NaN); // false
Console.Out.WriteLine(a == a); // false
Console.Out.WriteLine(double.IsNaN(a)); // true
```

Comment: As far as I can see, conditional breakpoints are evaluated at a particular source line.  Is that right?  The trouble is I have no idea where the NaN is coming from, which is why I'd just like the debugger to stop when it happens.

Comment: Yes, you have to set the breakpoint on a line of code.  However, you should be able to hone in on the source by adding breakpoints and rerunning the code.

Initially I thought the 'checked' keyword would help but in my tests it does not.

Comment: Yes, it appears that the IEEE floating point spec. mandates no exceptions for this situation.  Looks like I'll have to find it the hard way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're handling the exception somehow (like a catching a generic Exception) What you can do is press Ctrl+alt+E to bring up the exceptions dialog -- make sure you check the "when thrown" checkbox for the exception(s) you're interested in

Comment: No different.  It just keeps running.

Comment: In that case -- what makes you think the exception is being thrown? (my default is to stop on throwing of any managed exceptions to cover any eventualities). Conditional breakpoints could help as well

Comment: Well maybe it's not being thrown.  I wish it was.  Since the calculation is almost certainly within the XNA library's Vector3 member functions I don't have control over whether it lets exceptions out.  I'd expect "when thrown" to work there, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could set a [conditional breakpoint](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308469) that only breaks when the divisor of an expression is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but.....

from experience its nearly always Vector3.Normalize that i use by mistake.

When I'm not sure whether it will be zero length I now always do

float L = V.Length();
if(L != 0.0)
   V /= L;

divide by zero in Normalize should give an exception but it doesn't. Caused me a lot of head scratching.